# Is it possible to remove an empty parcel?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I do know how to make villagers leave, but the parcel stays once they're gone and eventually get filled by a new villager afterwards.

I have built 8 houses so far, can I go back on that and have only 3 houses on the island?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, there is no way to remove a house plot once it has been built.

My wife tried in her game, but when you are discussing island inhabitants, all Tom Nook allows you to do is move them, not remove them.

The only things you can remove seem to be bridges and stairs.